# Deleting duplicates based on fuzzy matching in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, matching, fuzzy

I have a DataFrame with people's informations, but there are duplicated rows with address slightly different.

How can i delete duplicates based on fuzzy matching or other way of detecting similarity but ensuring that row with similar address will be deleted only if first and last name are matching also?

Example data:

```
    First name | Last name | Address
0     John         Doe        ABC 9
1     John         Doe        KFT 2
2     Michael      John       ABC 9
3     Mary         Jane       PEP 9/2
4     Mary         Jane       PEP, 9-2
5     Gary         Young      verylongstreetname 1       
6     Gary         Young      1 verylongstretname
```

(typo in street in on purpose)

Code for example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['John', 'Doe', 'ABC 9'],
    ['John', 'Doe', 'KFT 2'],
    ['Michael', 'John', 'ABC 9'],
    ['Mary', 'Jane', 'PEP 9/2'],
    ['Mary', 'Jane', 'PEP, 9-2'],
    ['Gary', 'Young', 'verylongstreetname 1'],
    ['Gary', 'Young', '1 verylongstretname']
], columns=['First name', 'Last name', 'Address'])
```

Expected output:

```
    First name | Last name | Address
0     John         Doe        ABC 9
1     John         Doe        KFT 2
2     Michael      John       ABC 9
3     Mary         Jane       PEP 9/2
4     Gary         Young      verylongstreetname 1
```

Comment: some data would be nice..

Comment: Like @iamklaus already suggested, if you want good answers, you have to ask your question in the correct way. In your case it would be easier for us to answer if you provide example table (dataframe) and the expected output alsof in tabular format.

Comment: @Sinma Only you, human being, know what is similar and what is golden standard to what you should map your untidy data. Do not expect any ML algo to do this job instead of you. The best approach to solving your task is via setting fixed grep-and-replace rules and then dropping duplicates.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov i would be satisfied with deleting duplicates  with e.g. 90% similarity in address with Levenshtein distance or something. I wrote something almost working but it is terrible and slow.

Comment: If you have 10 "similar" candidates, with a chosen similarity score in excess of 0.9 (who said 0.9 is right, did you cross-validated it?), which one of 10 will you leave? I mean there is  lot of work should be done prior to fuzzywuzzy, Levinstein, cosine or any other similarity score.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov in my case it doesn't matter, they are equal to me and it can be first or random from that 10 candidates

Comment: You may think about (1) vectorizing your data via `sklearn`'s `CountVectorizer`  (2) calculating similarity matrix with `cosine` distance (3) dropping any data that have similarity in the range 1> similarity>0.9. For a reasonable amount of data, say millions rows, it should complete within minutes I suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `str.replace` to drop all non-word character and then `drop_duplicates`

```
df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.replace(r'\W','')
temp_address = df['Address']
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

**Output**

```
  First name Last name Address
0       John       Doe    ABC9
1       John       Doe    KFT2
2    Michael      John    ABC9
3       Mary      Jane   PEP92
```

Substituting Original Address

```
b['Address'] = b['Address'].apply(lambda x: [w for w in temp_address if w.split(' ')[0] in x][0])
```

**Output**

```
 First name Last name  Address
0       John       Doe    ABC 9
1       John       Doe    KFT 2
2    Michael      John    ABC 9
3       Mary      Jane  PEP 9/2
```

**Okay heres a way**

```
df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.replace(r'\W',' ') # giving a space

def check_simi(d):
    temp = []
    flag = 0
    for w in d:
        temp.extend(w.split(' '))
    temp = [t for t in temp if t]    
    flag = len(temp) / 2

    if len(set(temp)) == flag:
        return int(d.index[0])
    else:


indexes = df.groupby(['First name','Last name'])['Address'].apply(check_simi)
indexes = [int(i) for i in indexes if i >= 0]

df.drop(indexes)

  First name Last name               Address
0       John       Doe                 ABC 9
1       John       Doe                 KFT 2
2    Michael      John                 ABC 9
4       Mary      Jane              PEP  9 2
6       Gary     Young  1 verylongstreetname
```

PS - please look into https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy for much cleaner approach, i didn't since my network isn't allowing to do so

Comment: my bad, i updated example data showing one more case in which i don't think replace will be any help.

Comment: Thanks, based on your answer i created with fuzzy wuzzy working code that do was i was expected.

Answer (score 0):

## Solved.

Based on @iamklaus anwser i made this piece of code:

```
def remove_duplicates_inplace(df, groupby=[], similarity_field='', similar_level=85):
    def check_simi(d):
        dupl_indexes = []
        for i in range(len(d.values) - 1):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(d.values)):
                if fuzz.token_sort_ratio(d.values[i], d.values[j]) >= similar_level:
                    dupl_indexes.append(d.index[j])

        return dupl_indexes

    indexes = df.groupby(groupby)[similarity_field].apply(check_simi)

    for index_list in indexes:
        df.drop(index_list, inplace=True)


remove_duplicates_inplace(df, groupby=['firstname', 'lastname'], similarity_field='address')
```

Output:

```
  firstname lastname               address
0      John      Doe                 ABC 9
1      John      Doe                 KFT 2
2   Michael     John                 ABC 9
3      Mary     Jane               PEP 9/2
5      Gary    Young  verylongstreetname 1
```